# google maps marker link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to have my markers as links to each page associated with them. So far I have managed to put a link in the info box, but I want to bypass this and just have the marker as the link. I'm using gmaps4rails gem.

Controller

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@soiltemps) do |soiltemps, marker|
      location_link = view_context.link_to soiltemps.site, soiltemp_path(soiltemps)
      marker.lat soiltemps.latitude
      marker.lng soiltemps.longitude
      marker.picture({"url" => "/logo.png",
                      "width" =>  36,
                      "height" => 36})
      marker.infowindow "<h4><u>#{location_link}</u></h4> "
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@soiltemps) do |soiltemps, marker|
  marker.lat soiltemps.latitude
  marker.lng soiltemps.longitude
  marker.picture({"url" => "/logo.png",
                  "width" =>  36,
                  "height" => 36})
  marker.json({ link: soiltemp_url(soiltemps) })
end
```

and add the listeners in your js:

```
markers_json = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(markers_json);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    link = markers_json[i].link;
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i].getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
      window.open(link);
    })
  }

  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

Comment: Thanks apneadiving, seems to work, but opens a blank(tab) new window.

Comment: mmmm, could you copy paste the dom in a gist?

Comment: if you want help, I need info! :)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what a dom is? Rails newbie here. :)

Comment: copy paste al the html in your page in a gist

Comment: Right, I think I follow you. Thanks for your patience.  https://gist.github.com/tjyelds/7543886

Comment: I told you to use `soiltemp_url`, not `soiltemp_path`

Comment: I tried soiltemp_url but still had the same issue. I tried soiltemp_path to see what would happen but forgot to change the code back.

Comment: and whats the generated html when you use soiltemp_url?

Comment: but use soiltemp_url!

Comment: No luck on that update. Page loads fine, but markers when clicked don't go anywhere, they stay on the index view. Updated html here -> https://gist.github.com/tjyelds/7543886

Comment: ok due to counter not taken into account properly in loops, should be ok now

Comment: Great, works now, but opens in new tab. Is this because of window.open command? Would window.location work to open in same window event? Can;t thank you enough for your patience and help.

Comment: yes change with `window.location.href = ` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

For url to same window with back  - You can do:

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@soiltemps) do |soiltemps, marker|
  marker.lat soiltemps.latitude
  marker.lng soiltemps.longitude
  marker.picture({"url" => "/logo.png",
                  "width" =>  36,
                  "height" => 36})
  marker.json({ link: soiltemp_url(soiltemps) })
end
```

and add the listeners in your js:

markers

```
_json = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(markers_json);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    link = markers_json[i].link;
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i].getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
      window.location.assign(link);
    })
  }

  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

### More on window location assign (link)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp